# How to delete rows from multiple tables based on specific condition in mysql php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql

i created 7 tables in mysql database using phpmyadmin. From those 
  CAM_INFO Table is parent table for all 6 tables...and the structure is below

[image]

CAM_INFO table having "CODE" field having unique value generated by some random function in php...

And i have child table like "CANON" in that also i'm having same structure

[image]ucture

All i want is when i delete row from CAM_INFO(parent table ) based on some condition...it will also delete in child table "CANON" having the same unique value in "CODE" field..

similarly it will also checks all 6 tables having the CODE field which is having the unique value..

Comment: You can use a trigger.

Comment: how? can you provide some sample code

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Comment: you can use foreign key concept. So if record deleted from master table, records from child tables automatically deleted

Comment: for achievieng this you have to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: I think if i implement foreign key concept, In parent table(cam_info) the CODE filed must be defined as PRIMARY KEY... right? but i dont want to set that CODE field AS PRIMARY KEY..

Comment: what is the primary key of the cam_info table currently? Is every value of CODE in cam_info different to every other (i.e. they are completely unique)? If it is, then it ought to be the primary key. If it's not, then I can't see how you can use it to reliably delete the right values from Canon when a single row of cam_info is deleted, because that CODE value might be somewhere else in cam_info (if so then maybe shouldn't actually delete anything??), and also it seems like you might delete things connected to other userIDs, which I guess might not be the intention. Can you clarify?

Comment: Look bro...in can_info table...no field is having primary key.. My intension is when I insert data into can_info table...based on the name of camera I insert same details into appropriate table..for example if user enters nicon camera details...it will store in can_info table as well as nicon table...in both tables code field containing value is unique... I want to delete data from both tables based on that code field value...is it possible..

Comment: "no field is having primary key". That's a really bad idea. Every table needs a primary key, even if it's a compound one (i.e. made of multiple fields). That's one of the most basic principles of good database design. It stops you accidentally creating bad data. You say ".in both tables code field containing value is unique.". If that's true then quite simply CODE should be defined as your primary key. Then you can use cascading deletes.

Comment: But...why are you duplicating data in this way at all? If you're literally just storing the same data in both tables...that's completely pointless copying. There is no need. A database should not contain any duplicated or copied information. If the intention is to signify the type of camera, then you already have the cam_name and cam_model fields to tell you this, and you can use that information when you write a query, to fetch all cameras of a certain type (for example). Why do you even need to copy the data, do you think?

Comment: I wonder if you would benefit from taking some time to study entity-relationships and database normalisation, which you can find free materials and tutorials about online, and plenty of them. It will help you to create better and more efficient database designs, and save you problems like this, which don't even need worry you.

Comment: @ADyson with your comments... i realized my mistake.... now i got full clarity...thanks a lot.